# Spring Batch Job gets completed but its thread never got destroyed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am having one job in the spring batch application which got successfully completed but after completion, its thread goes to waiting state. As more instances of job get executed, number of threads of tomcat keeps on increasing.

**Here is the Job Configuration :**

```
@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
@Qualifier(value = "job1")
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step1())
            .end()
            .preventRestart()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Buylead, Buylead>chunk(10000)
            .reader(itemReader())
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .build();
}

public JdbcCursorItemReader<Buylead> itemReader() {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Buylead> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setSql(" --- WHatever Query ----");
    reader.setRowMapper(new MapperBL());

    return reader;
}

public ItemWriter<Buylead> itemWriter(){
    FlatFileItemWriter<Buylead> itemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter() ;

    itemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("output/buyleadSolrDoc.xls"));
    itemWriter.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Buylead>() { {
                setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Buylead>() { {
                    setNames(new String[] {*************** }); } }); } });
    itemWriter.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);
    return itemWriter;
}
```

And data Source is kept in another configuration class.

And **here is the Main class**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Application  extends DefaultBatchConfigurer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SearchApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // override to do not set datasource even if a datasource exist.
        // initialize will use a Map based JobRepository (instead of database)
    }

}
```

The job is getting executed successfully. But its thread goes to wait state.

And **here is the portion of ThreadDump for the application**

```
http-nio-8080-exec-2" #22 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.11ms elapsed=29.43s tid=0x00007fcb6d6ddd60 nid=0xc724 waiting on condition  [0x00007fcae3ffe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@15.0.1/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000713c00710> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@15.0.1/LockSupport.java:341)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(java.base@15.0.1/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:505)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(java.base@15.0.1/ForkJoinPool.java:3137)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@15.0.1/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1614)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(java.base@15.0.1/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:33)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@15.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@15.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1116)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@15.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@15.0.1/Thread.java:832)*
```

Please suggest the way to close the thread which is in Park state.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch does not create or manage threads directly. It delegates that to a `TaskExecutor` implementation in different places:

- The `JobLauncher` delegates to a task executor to launch jobs
- The `StepBuilder` delegates to a task executor to create multi-threaded steps
- The `FlowBuilder` delegates to a task executor to create split flows and run steps in parallel
- The `AsyncItemProcessor` delegates to a task executor to process items asynchronously in separate threads
- The `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` delegates to a task executor to handle partitions in different threads
- etc

In all these cases, threads life cycle is managed by the underlying `TaskExecutor` implementation. If you use a task executor with Spring Batch, you need to make sure that it is correctly stopped/shutdown once it is not needed anymore. From what you shared, you do not seem to use a task executor in your Spring Batch configuration, so you should have a task executor defined somewhere in your application context which is not stopped correctly.